# Javascript Jquery Scroll Offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I want the page change after I scroll and offset > 600 and < 1200. I tried `if ($('html').scrollTop() >= 600 && $('html').scrollTop() <= 1260)` but it just work once. How can it continuously?

Comment: try adding the code inside the `scroll` event. $( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
// code here
});

Answer (score 0):

To have this update on scroll, you will want to use an event listener. Specifically, the `scroll` listener in jQuery.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
  // conditional here.
});
```

You can view the list of jQuery events here - https://api.jquery.com/category/events/.